# jquery, need similar functionality of disable for select optoins

Tags: jquery

I am using coding like this:

```
                \$(this).attr("disabled", 'disabled');
            \$(this).removeAttr("disabled");
```

This would only disable the option. I want to have the same accessibility and coding but I would prefer to make it invisible on the drop down menu instead.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to `remove()` it and re-add them. You *could* try `hide()` and `show()`, but at least IE won't support it.

Comment: oie...i have like dynamic select menu generations ... i would have to store all these values somewhere...